# How to fetch text from span (class) using DomDocument

Tags: php, html-parsing, domdocument, domxpath

I'm new to domdocument. I'm trying to fetch plaintext or inner text from the span tag that belongs to a specific class

For example

```
<span class="test">hello world</span> // Need to retrieve hello world text
```

This is what I have done so far

```
$dom = new domDocument;
@ $dom->loadHTML($url);
$classname="test";
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$spaner = $finder->query("//span[contains(@class, '$classname')]"); // this returns  [length] => 2 which means two classes present with the name of "test", I need to fetch the first one
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Assuming that your target `<span>` is the first in the `$dom`, try this:

```
$spaner = $finder->query("//span[contains(@class, '$classname')][1]");
echo $spaner[0]->textContent
```

;
Output should be:

```
hello world
```